# How do telegram determine user language

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

API object [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) has property `language_code` - how do Telegram determine user's language, and how do I change it?

I wish to create response for user  based on `language_code` language, but I am not sure I can trust this value, because fore example my `language_code` is `'en'`, but for the chatting or UI I am using another one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each Update from Telegram contains User information (in `Message`, in `InlineQuery` or some other). This `language_code` is based on which language is set as default on user's device or set for Telegram app. You can trust it.

But some users may want to change a language just for your bot. For that you can add your custom "Settings" to your bot menu, with all languages you support.